# This code works fine but my intuition is telling me that it's way slower than it need's to be

Tags: python, list, set

The purpose of this code is to solve for the Collatz Sequence. If you are not familiar this is the sequence:

Take a number N

If N is Odd:
N = 3N + 1

If N is Even:
N = N/2

Iterate until N = 1

10 --> 5 --> 16 --> --> 8 --> 4 --> 2 --> 1

My basic code operates on the assumption that once you find a value, the sequence it has is always going to be the same. So once you have solved for 10, you can "sieve" it from your list similar to primes.

The values here by the way are finding the longest sequence under 1,000,000 with the reasoning that all numbers under 500,000 will have a multiple of 2 under 1,000,000 so they will never have the longest sequence.

***Code:***

```
list_of_tries = [*range(500000, 1000000)]
set_of_past_tries = set()
past_str = []
for x in list_of_tries:
  new_str = []
  if x not in set_of_past_tries:
    x == 1
  if x != 1:
    new_str.append(x)
  while x != 1:
    if x % 2 == 0:
      x /= 2
      new_str.append(x)
      set_of_past_tries.add(x)
    else:
      x *= 3
      x += 1
      new_str.append(x)
      set_of_past_tries.add(x)
  if len(new_str) > len(past_str):
    past_str = new_str
```

I'd like it to store every sequence, so once it finds that X = 10 for example it would just stop and print the sequence it knows already, but I don't have any idea how to do that quickly.

And at the end of the day the code works, it's just slow. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: The instruction `x == 1` does nothing useful in the beginning of the code. Is it intended? Moreover, `x /= 2` change the type of `x` which is converted to a float (not an int anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about Memoization is incorrect. You cannot just start at 500,000 because if you look at 999,998, you will divide by 2 and get 499,999, for which you will have no cached value. You are correct that values under 500,000 will never be the answer to the longest series, however, you do need to know the series below 500,000 for optimized sequence generation.

You really want to store the series you've seen so far in a `dict` keyed to the given `N` value and you need to start at the beginning 1 to take full advantage of the caching.

A modified version of [this algorithm](https://www.pythonpool.com/collatz-sequence-python/#h-longest-collatz-sequence-python) can be used to get "every sequence" as you requested.

```py
def longest_collatz_sequence(upper_bound):
    assert upper_bound >= 2  # upper_bound needs to be longer than prepopulated cache
    upper_bound += 1
    cache = {n: [] for n in range(1, upper_bound)}

    cache[1] = []
    cache[2] = [1]

    for n in range(3, upper_bound):
        sequence = []
        current = n
        while n > 1:
            if n < current:
                sequence.extend(cache[n])
                cache[current] = sequence
                break
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n // 2
            else:
                n = 3 * n + 1
            sequence.append(n)
    return cache


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = longest_collatz_sequence(1_000_000)
    longest_series_start, longest_series = max(d.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]))
    series = [longest_series_start, *longest_series]
    print(f"Longest Series Where N = {longest_series_start}.")
    print(f"Longest Series is {series}")
    print(f"Longest Series is {len(series)} steps.")
```

You can then print out the returned dictionary to see every possible Collatz Sequence in the range 1 to `upper_bound` inclusive.

You can find the longest series using the [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function with a specified key, you can build the longest series by joining the `N` value stored in the key with the rest of the series stored in the values.

The above program outputs:

```py
Longest Series Where N = 837799.
Longest Series is [837799, 2513398, 1256699, 3770098, 1885049, 5655148, 2827574, 1413787, 4241362, 2120681, 6362044, 3181022, 1590511, 4771534, 2385767, 7157302, 3578651, 10735954, 5367977, 16103932, 8051966, 4025983, 12077950, 6038975, 18116926, 9058463, 27175390, 13587695, 40763086, 20381543, 61144630, 30572315, 91716946, 45858473, 137575420, 68787710, 34393855, 103181566, 51590783, 154772350, 77386175, 232158526, 116079263, 348237790, 174118895, 522356686, 261178343, 783535030, 391767515, 1175302546, 587651273, 1762953820, 881476910, 440738455, 1322215366, 661107683, 1983323050, 991661525, 2974984576, 1487492288, 743746144, 371873072, 185936536, 92968268, 46484134, 23242067, 69726202, 34863101, 104589304, 52294652, 26147326, 13073663, 39220990, 19610495, 58831486, 29415743, 88247230, 44123615, 132370846, 66185423, 198556270, 99278135, 297834406, 148917203, 446751610, 223375805, 670127416, 335063708, 167531854, 83765927, 251297782, 125648891, 376946674, 188473337, 565420012, 282710006, 141355003, 424065010, 212032505, 636097516, 318048758, 159024379, 477073138, 238536569, 715609708, 357804854, 178902427, 536707282, 268353641, 805060924, 402530462, 201265231, 603795694, 301897847, 905693542, 452846771, 1358540314, 679270157, 2037810472, 1018905236, 509452618, 254726309, 764178928, 382089464, 191044732, 95522366, 47761183, 143283550, 71641775, 214925326, 107462663, 322387990, 161193995, 483581986, 241790993, 725372980, 362686490, 181343245, 544029736, 272014868, 136007434, 68003717, 204011152, 102005576, 51002788, 25501394, 12750697, 38252092, 19126046, 9563023, 28689070, 14344535, 43033606, 21516803, 64550410, 32275205, 96825616, 48412808, 24206404, 12103202, 6051601, 18154804, 9077402, 4538701, 13616104, 6808052, 3404026, 1702013, 5106040, 2553020, 1276510, 638255, 1914766, 957383, 2872150, 1436075, 4308226, 2154113, 6462340, 3231170, 1615585, 4846756, 2423378, 1211689, 3635068, 1817534, 908767, 2726302, 1363151, 4089454, 2044727, 6134182, 3067091, 9201274, 4600637, 13801912, 6900956, 3450478, 1725239, 5175718, 2587859, 7763578, 3881789, 11645368, 5822684, 2911342, 1455671, 4367014, 2183507, 6550522, 3275261, 9825784, 4912892, 2456446, 1228223, 3684670, 1842335, 5527006, 2763503, 8290510, 4145255, 12435766, 6217883, 18653650, 9326825, 27980476, 13990238, 6995119, 20985358, 10492679, 31478038, 15739019, 47217058, 23608529, 70825588, 35412794, 17706397, 53119192, 26559596, 13279798, 6639899, 19919698, 9959849, 29879548, 14939774, 7469887, 22409662, 11204831, 33614494, 16807247, 50421742, 25210871, 75632614, 37816307, 113448922, 56724461, 170173384, 85086692, 42543346, 21271673, 63815020, 31907510, 15953755, 47861266, 23930633, 71791900, 35895950, 17947975, 53843926, 26921963, 80765890, 40382945, 121148836, 60574418, 30287209, 90861628, 45430814, 22715407, 68146222, 34073111, 102219334, 51109667, 153329002, 76664501, 229993504, 114996752, 57498376, 28749188, 14374594, 7187297, 21561892, 10780946, 5390473, 16171420, 8085710, 4042855, 12128566, 6064283, 18192850, 9096425, 27289276, 13644638, 6822319, 20466958, 10233479, 30700438, 15350219, 46050658, 23025329, 69075988, 34537994, 17268997, 51806992, 25903496, 12951748, 6475874, 3237937, 9713812, 4856906, 2428453, 7285360, 3642680, 1821340, 910670, 455335, 1366006, 683003, 2049010, 1024505, 3073516, 1536758, 768379, 2305138, 1152569, 3457708, 1728854, 864427, 2593282, 1296641, 3889924, 1944962, 972481, 2917444, 1458722, 729361, 2188084, 1094042, 547021, 1641064, 820532, 410266, 205133, 615400, 307700, 153850, 76925, 230776, 115388, 57694, 28847, 86542, 43271, 129814, 64907, 194722, 97361, 292084, 146042, 73021, 219064, 109532, 54766, 27383, 82150, 41075, 123226, 61613, 184840, 92420, 46210, 23105, 69316, 34658, 17329, 51988, 25994, 12997, 38992, 19496, 9748, 4874, 2437, 7312, 3656, 1828, 914, 457, 1372, 686, 343, 1030, 515, 1546, 773, 2320, 1160, 580, 290, 145, 436, 218, 109, 328, 164, 82, 41, 124, 62, 31, 94, 47, 142, 71, 214, 107, 322, 161, 484, 242, 121, 364, 182, 91, 274, 137, 412, 206, 103, 310, 155, 466, 233, 700, 350, 175, 526, 263, 790, 395, 1186, 593, 1780, 890, 445, 1336, 668, 334, 167, 502, 251, 754, 377, 1132, 566, 283, 850, 425, 1276, 638, 319, 958, 479, 1438, 719, 2158, 1079, 3238, 1619, 4858, 2429, 7288, 3644, 1822, 911, 2734, 1367, 4102, 2051, 6154, 3077, 9232, 4616, 2308, 1154, 577, 1732, 866, 433, 1300, 650, 325, 976, 488, 244, 122, 61, 184, 92, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
Longest Series is 525 steps.
```

I ran [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) on this implementation and your implementation.

```
Original Implementation: 348.300429 
Modified Implementation: 46.332222100000024
```

---

**Note:** This modification only makes sense if you do, in fact, need every sequence in the range. If you only want the longest sequence, you should use the unmodified algorithm get `837799` and generate the series using the Generator from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/229275) on CodeReview.

```py
def longest_collatz_sequence(upper_bound):
    assert upper_bound >= 2  # upper_bound needs to be longer than prepopulated cache
    upper_bound += 1
    cache = {n: 0 for n in range(1, upper_bound)}

    cache[1] = 1
    cache[2] = 2

    for n in range(3, upper_bound):
        counter = 0
        current = n
        while n > 1:
            if n < current:
                cache[current] = cache[n] + counter
                break
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n / 2
                counter += 1
            else:
                n = 3 * n + 1
                counter += 1
    return cache


def collatz_gen(starting_num):
    yield starting_num

    num = starting_num
    while num > 1:
        num = (num // 2) if num % 2 == 0 else (3 * num + 1)
        yield num


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = longest_collatz_sequence(1_000_000)
    longest_series_start = list(d.values()).index(max(d.values())) + 1
    series = list(collatz_gen(longest_series_start))
    print(f"Longest Series Where N = {longest_series_start}.")
    print(f"Longest Series is {series}")
    print(f"Longest Series is {len(series)} steps.")
```

[timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) measured this implementation at `24.5141495` including generating the longest sequence.